# Cloud Foundry more then 10 ports for an app by curl

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-cli

I have running app in Cloud Foundry. I would like to proceed the procedure of adding more then 10 ports to the app described here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/custom-ports.html#procedure

When I am trying to add more then 10 ports, I am getting an error:

```
cf curl /v2/apps/c5476e63-d1d2-4eb7-a757-18cff957bc5a -X PUT -d '{"ports": [2030,2031,2032,2033,2034,2035,2036,2037,2038,2039,2040,2041,2042]}' 

{
   "description": "The app is invalid: Process must have at most 10 exposed ports.",
   "error_code": "CF-AppInvalid",
   "code": 100001
}
```

I tried to adjust some quota definitions like total_routes (-1) or total_reserved_route_ports (-1) but without any result. Why do I get this error and how can I assign more then 10 ports by cf curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing this, it would appear to be an arbitrary and hardcoded limit that cannot be changed.

See https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/blob/master/app/models/runtime/constraints/ports_policy.rb#L9:

```
 def validate
    return if @process.ports.nil? || @process.ports.empty?
    return @errors.add('Process', 'must have at most 10 exposed ports.') if ports_limit_exceeded?
    return @errors.add('Ports', 'must be integers.') unless all_ports_are_integers?
    ...
```

and https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/blob/master/app/models/runtime/constraints/ports_policy.rb#L44, which defines the limit.

```
  def ports_limit_exceeded?
    @process.ports.length > 10
  end
```

Comment: I found that I can add more then 10 ports to the app simply by using a command  "cf map-route", for example: cf map-route APP tcp.shared-domain.com --port 2030

Comment: That's doing something different. If you look at the graphic from the link you included, that is configuring the route port. You can configure as many route ports as you are permitted by your quota. What you were originally asking about is configuring the app port (again, see the diagram in the docs). The app port is the actual port on which your app listens for traffic. By default, it's 8080 and there is just one. So if you have two route ports mapped, say 65000 and 65001, both would be delivered to your app listening on port 8080. i.e. 65000 -> 8080 and 65001 -> 8080.

Comment: If you just want externally available ports, using `cf map-route` is fine. If your app itself is actually listening on more than 10 different ports, that won't help. The number of app ports is hard coded at 10 max.